# How to avoid assigning nothing to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, error-handling

I think this is a short question but knowing it will save me much work. I really appreciate your help!

I get data from API, I store all data into variables for later use but sometimes the API sends incomplete data so **I want the variable that is not found to be set to 'Unknown'**.

```
unknown_data = 'Unknown'
    
data = all_information['result'] or unknown_data
business_status = data['business_status'] or unknown_data
address = data['formatted_address'] or unknown_data
lat = data['geometry']['location']['lat'] or unknown_data
lang = data['geometry']['location']['lng'] or unknown_data
name = data['name'] or unknown_data
industry = data['types'] or unknown_data
phone = data['international_phone_number'] or unknown_data
website = data['website'] or unknown_data
```

I thought about using `try except` but I think it will make my code too long. Why the method I am using `'var = data['item'] or unknown_data'` is not working and what can do its job?

Comment: How do you know the data is incomplete? How would python know the data is incomplete?

Comment: If you're asking about how to avoid the `KeyError`, use `get` instead of `[]` to do the lookup. Your code will work then (assuming, the valid data will never be empty/Falsey).

Comment: assuming all_information is a dictionary -you can get a  None by: 
data = all_information.get('result') or unknown_data

Comment: `all_information.get('result') or unknown_data` did the trick! thank you so much Carcigenicate & adhg!!

Comment: FYI, `all_information.get('result', unknown_data)` would actually be the cleaner way. The second argument is the default value to use.